# HTML + CSS, i cant seem to get two horizontally alligned divs to line up

Tags: css, html

I have two div inside a third, I want the borders to line up but whilst they are next to eachother one is inexplicably slightly lower than the other ...

```
<div class="application">
                <div class="contactMeForm">

                        Contact Us
                        Please provide as much information as possible about your query</br>
                        If you are requesting a quote this will help us to better estimate the costs involved.

                    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                        <table width="450px">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top""><label for="last_name">Last Name *</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><label for="email">Email Address *</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="enquiry" value="Website Solution Quote">Website Solution Quote</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><label for="comments">Enquiry Nature *</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="enquiry" value="Mobile Solution Quote">Mobile Solution Quote</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"></td>
                                <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="enquiry" value="Other">Other</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"> <label for="comments">Comments *</label></td>
                                <td valign="top"><textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="contactMeHelp">

                    Extra details on how to fill in the form

                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the CSS for the three divs

```
.application {
width: 97%;
margin: 20px 2% 0px 2%;
text-align: center;
display: block;
border: 2px #000000 solid;

}

.contactMeForm {
display: inline-block;
border: 5px #9E9FA1 solid;
border-right: 0px;
width: 49%;
color: #48494B;
text-align: left;
}

.contactMeHelp {
display: inline-block;
border: 5px #9E9FA1 solid;
border-left: 0px;
width: 49%;
color: #48494B;
text-align: right;
}
```

This is how it currently looks
http://masterzangetsu.eu/ContactMe/

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

To your two `div`s

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "float: right;" to the .contactMeHelp element. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1.) You do not have your `float` parameters set for each of your containing divs. Setting them to `left` and `right` depending on where they should be will fix it.

2.) Doing the above will still leave some weird block alignment in the `.application` div. This is because its height of the right-most div is not stretched to its parent div, you can do this by setting the `height:100%`.

Here is a fiddle showing you the results: http://jsfiddle.net/5T3NC/

Comment: he/she is using `inline-block` instead of `float`, you don't need both. And for your #2 that's because you need to clear floating elements. You can use a clearfix or a `div` after the floated elements set to `clear:both;`

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tip. I've heard the word clearfix thrown around before, do you mind explaning your last sentence again? Which `div` would need to be set to `clear:both`?

Comment: sure, instead of using a clearfix what you could do is put in an empty `div` below the floated elements like this:
    <div class="float-left"></div>
    <div class="floar-right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
and set `clear` to: `.clear{clear:both;}` and that's the same as using a clearfix

Comment: most people will just use clearfix because it applies `clear:both` to the css `:after` selector so it does the same thing with out having to add another `div` to your HTML, but either will work